# ngStorage in select with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use ionic, and I have a select where I choose one of two options for performing arithmetic operations with them after. Use ngStorage to save, but I would also apply to the select the option itself and always keep the user chooses in ngStorage supporting me as I do with the input of "write a number", any help?

http://codepen.io/maestromutenrroy/pen/ivgIH

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','ngStorage'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {

    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        c6: 1,
        c12: 2
    });   

    $scope.results = {};

    $scope.templates = [{
            name: '5',
            url: 'template1.html'
        },
        {
            name: '10',
            url: 'template2.html'
    }];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];

  })
```

Thank you!

Comment: i'm trying really hard to understand your question, but I come as far as that you would like the select option to stay on the last selected option? is that correct?

Comment: Yes its correct, Sorry for mi english. The idea is to initially charge the second option ($ = $ scope.template scope.templates [1];), but after one time it user choose other option in the select dropdown, and reload this page, it select dropdown save the option for it in user memory local Storage.

Answer (score 0):

In your codepen, you are binding the number input using $storage:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="$storage.c6" ...>
```

This will make the value of the input field persist between page reloads.
However, you bind the  to a $scope variable which is not part of $storage:

```
<select ng-model="template" ...>
```

so this value is reset to default when the page is reloaded.

To have the  stay on the last selected option you need to store your "template" variable in $storage too.